# In Ruby on Rails Devise: How to Plug Some Code to Handle the Current User When S/he Logs Out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Basically, I want to log something about the current user when s/he logs out.

I am trying to override `after_sign_out_path_for`:

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
  # Notice that differently from +after_sign_in_path_for+ this method
  # receives a symbol with the scope, and not the resource.

  # puts current_user.id

  new_user_session_path
end
```

But the method `current_user` sometimes it returns `nil`, and from this ticket (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/pull/2022), it seems `current_user` is not available in `after_sign_out_path_for`.

What should I do? Do I have to override other methods? Like: `sign_out_and_redirect`? Are the any cleaner way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
before_filter :log_user_logout, only: [:destroy]
```

and access `current_user` within that method

Comment: I finally extended `Devise::SessionsController`, and overridden the `destroy` action.